# javascript webrtc cancel negotiation

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

How can i cancel this webrtc function:

```js
function negotiate() {
    return pc.createOffer({"offerToReceiveAudio":true,"offerToReceiveVideo":true}).then(function(offer) {
        return pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
    }).then(function() {
        // wait for ICE gathering to complete
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            console.log(pc.iceGatheringState);
            if (pc.iceGatheringState === 'complete') {
                resolve();
            } else {
                function checkState() {
                    console.log(pc.iceGatheringState);
                    if (pc.iceGatheringState === 'complete') {
                        pc.removeEventListener('icegatheringstatechange', checkState);
                        resolve();
                    }
                }
                pc.addEventListener('icegatheringstatechange', checkState);

            }
        });
    }).then(function() {
        var offer = pc.localDescription;
        
        return timeoutPromise(30000, fetch('/offer', {
            body: JSON.stringify({
                sdp: offer.sdp,
                type: offer.type,
                "name":name,
                "surname":surname
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'POST'
        }));
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(answer) {
        if (answer.sdp == "" && answer.type == ""){
            setTimeout(call_rejected, 1000);
            return null;
        }else{
            return pc.setRemoteDescription(answer);
        }
    }).catch(function(e) {
        //alert(e);
        console.log(e);
    });
    
}
```

It would be nice if i can stop it in any stage of running (for example terminating /offer request).

The code of timeoutPromise is:

```js
function timeoutPromise(ms, promise) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      reject(new Error("promise timeout"))
    }, ms);
    promise.then(
      (res) => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        resolve(res);
      },
      (err) => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        reject(err);
      }
    );
  })
}
```

Maybe if i use a global boolean variable to reject every stage after an if statement is a solution but i am not familiar with javascript Promises (resolve - reject).